# bash assign output of fuser to a variable oddity

Tags: bash, fuser

when using the following bash script to assign variable to the output of fuser, it still outputs the part of result(before :) of fuser to screen.
why isn't it suppressed?  I suspect it has to do with the ":" char output by fuser.  how do I fix this?

```
test=`fuser -f /home/whois_database_collection_v4/whoisdatacollector/logs/com_log_2013_02_15_12_40_43.log`
/home/whois_database_collection_v4/whoisdatacollector/logs/com_log_2013_02_15_12_40_43.log:
```

Answer (score 1):

`fuser` sends the part of the output you see to `stderr`, and the rest to `stdout` (I suspect that it tries to simplify its usage from scripts, while preserving some beauty from the user's point of view). It will disappear if you add `2> /dev/null` redirection for stderr.